# ESP32 Access Point to get credentials return wifi:Association comeback time

Tags: c++, arduino, wifi, iot, esp32

I am trying to make AP server for getting wifi credentials. If I wait too long (it changes but for about 2 minute) to connect AP or to write id and password, it gives this error :

```
E (168130) wifi:Association refused temporarily, comeback time 268435 mSec
E (168130) wifi:Association comeback time (268435) mSec too long. max allowed 5000 mSec
 E (168738) wifi:Association refused temporarily, comeback time 268435 mSec
 E (168738) wifi:Association comeback time (268435) mSec too long. max allowed 5000 mSec
```

I am writing id and password correctly but I don't know, it gives this error. After this error I am writing same id and password, it connects. Why is this happening ? My full code here:(except html because its too long )

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

WebServer server(80);
const char PAGE_MAIN[] PROGMEM = R"=====(  html codes )=====";

String page = PAGE_MAIN; // Convert const char[] to String
boolean tryToConnect = true;

const char* accessPointName = "accespoint";      
const char* accessPointPassword = "accespointpassword"; 
char ssid[50];    
char password[50];  
String ssidlist = "";

void handleRoot() {
  server.send(200, "text/html", page); // Send the modified page
}

void handleSave() {
  String newSSID = server.arg("security");
  String newPassword = server.arg("password");
  tryToConnect = true;
  newSSID.toCharArray(ssid, sizeof(ssid));
  newPassword.toCharArray(password, sizeof(password));

  WiFi.disconnect(true); // Disconnect from the current network, forgetting it
  delay(100);
  
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.println(password);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.print("Connecting...");
  unsigned long startTime = millis(); 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && tryToConnect) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
    if (millis() - startTime > 10000) {
      tryToConnect = false;
      Serial.println(""); 
      String response = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'></head>";
      response += "<body><h1>Wrong password, please try again</h1>";
      response += "<a href='/'>Go back</a></body></html>"; 
      server.send(200, "text/html", response);
      server.sendHeader("Location", "/", true);
      server.send(302, "text/plain", ""); 
    }
  }
if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Connect, new IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    String response = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'></head>";
    response = "<body><h1>Password correct.</h1>";
    server.send(200, "text/html", response);
    delay(5000);
    server.stop();
    WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);
  }
}

void wifiInit(){
  WiFi.softAP(accessPointName, accessPointPassword);
  Serial.println("Access point started.");

  // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n == 0) {
      Serial.println("no networks found");
  } else {
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.println(" networks found");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      //Serial.print(i + 1);
      //Serial.print(": ");
      //Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));   
      //Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == WIFI_AUTH_OPEN)?" ":"*");
      delay(10);
      ssidlist += WiFi.SSID(i) + ",";
    }
  }
  page.replace("--ssidlist--", ssidlist); // Perform the replace operation
  Serial.println(ssidlist);
  Serial.println("");
  delay(2000);
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/save", handleSave);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("Access point ip adress ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  wifiInit();
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the WiFiManager library. It has the WiFi provisioning solved.

---

To join an AP esp8266 must change the WiFi radio channel to the channel of the AP. Since the esp8266 has only one radio, the SoftAP must change the channel too. This causes the SoftAP clients to disconnect.

The solution is respond to the configuration request before connecting to AP, then let the configuration page do a new request for the result.

To illustrate here is a simple example:

```
#ifdef ESP32
#include <WiFi.h>
#else
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#endif

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);

#ifdef ESP32
//  WiFi.begin(); // use SSID and password stored by SDK. commented out to test the Configuration AP
#else
//  WiFi.disconnect(); // forget the persistent connection to test the Configuration AP
#endif

  // waiting for connection to remembered  Wifi network
  Serial.println("Waiting for connection to WiFi");
  WiFi.waitForConnectResult();

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Could not connect to WiFi. Starting configuration AP...");
    configAP();
  } else {
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  }
}

void loop() {
}

void configAP() {

  WiFiServer configWebServer(80);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); // starts the default AP (factory default or setup as persistent)

  Serial.print("Connect your computer to the WiFi network ");
#ifdef ESP32
  Serial.print("to SSID of you ESP32"); // no getter for SoftAP SSID
#else
  Serial.print(WiFi.softAPSSID());
#endif
  Serial.println();
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("and enter http://");
  Serial.print(ip);
  Serial.println(" in a Web browser");

  configWebServer.begin();

  while (true) {

    WiFiClient client = configWebServer.available();
    if (client) {
      char line[64];
      int l = client.readBytesUntil('\n', line, sizeof(line));
      line[l] = 0;
      client.find((char*) "\r\n\r\n");
      if (strncmp_P(line, PSTR("POST"), strlen("POST")) == 0) {
        l = client.readBytes(line, sizeof(line));
        line[l] = 0;

        // parse the parameters sent by the html form
        const char* delims = "=&";
        strtok(line, delims);
        const char* ssid = strtok(NULL, delims);
        strtok(NULL, delims);
        const char* pass = strtok(NULL, delims);

        // send a response before attemting to connect to the WiFi network
        // because it will reset the SoftAP and disconnect the client station
        client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
        client.println(F("Connection: close"));
        client.println(F("Refresh: 10")); // send a request after 10 seconds
        client.println();
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>Configuration AP</h3><br>connecting...</body></html>"));
        client.stop();

        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
        Serial.println(ssid);
        WiFi.persistent(true);
        WiFi.setAutoConnect(true);
        WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
        WiFi.waitForConnectResult();

        // configuration continues with the next request

      } else {

        client.println(F("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"));
        client.println(F("Connection: close"));
        client.println();
        client.println(F("<html><body><h3>Configuration AP</h3><br>"));

        int status = WiFi.status();
        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
          client.println(F("Connection successful. Ending AP."));
        } else {
          client.println(F("<form action='/' method='POST'>WiFi connection failed. Enter valid parameters, please.<br><br>"));
          client.println(F("SSID:<br><input type='text' name='i'><br>"));
          client.println(F("Password:<br><input type='password' name='p'><br><br>"));
          client.println(F("<input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>"));
        }
        client.println(F("</body></html>"));
        client.stop();

        if (status == WL_CONNECTED) {
          delay(1000); // to let the SDK finish the communication
          Serial.println("Connection successful. Ending AP.");
          configWebServer.stop();
          WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```